# Using Oracle XE, how do I create a CASE statement To return a specific date

Tags: date, case, oracle-xe

I am Trying to create a view based on a business calendar table called Business Payment Calendar view with two new calculated columns:

1. Payment Warning Date (`Payment_Warning_Date`)
2. Payment Due Date (`Payment_Due_Date`)

And, also the non-calculated `Transaction_Date`

Those dates are based on the number of **BUSINESS** days from the transaction date from the business calendar, 7 and 10 business days. The Business Calendar table contains columns populated for the year.

```
CAL_Date (which is our datestamp),
Day_Name,
Month_Name,
Cal_Year,
Month_Num,
Weekend (True/False),
Holiday (True/False),
Bus_Working_Day (True/False).
```

So for example, say you have a purchase today, the output will be:

```
Transaction_Date: 6/26/2017 
Payment Warning Date: 7/6/2017
Payment Due Date: 7/11/2017
```

Figure we have the weekend coming up, next Monday (July 3) is a work day, but Tuesday (July 4) is a US holiday, then 3 more work days.

I'm just not having any luck building a case statement that properly takes into account the Bus_Working_Day field for SYSDATE+7 and +10 and then return the correct date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will generate a list showing the current date, and the warning and due dates for the current date.

```
CREATE TABLE myCal (CAL_Date date,
Bus_Working_Day int)

INSERT INTO myCal
SELECT DATE '2017-06-27', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-06-28', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-06-29', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-06-30', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-01', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-02', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-03', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-04', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-05', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-06', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-07', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-08', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-09', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-10', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-11', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-12', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-13', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-14', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-15', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-16', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-17', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-18', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-19', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-20', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2017-07-21', 1 FROM DUAL
;

SELECT cal.CAL_Date
      ,warn.Warning_Date
      ,due.Due_Date
  FROM myCal cal
         LEFT  JOIN (SELECT mn.CAL_Date
                           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mn.CAL_Date ORDER BY alt.CAL_DATE) as rn
                           ,alt.CAL_Date as Warning_Date
                       FROM myCal mn
                              INNER JOIN myCal alt ON (alt.CAL_Date > mn.CAL_Date)
                      WHERE alt.Bus_Working_Day = 1
                    ) warn ON (cal.CAL_Date = warn.CAL_Date AND warn.rn = 7)
         LEFT  JOIN (SELECT mn.CAL_Date
                           ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mn.CAL_Date ORDER BY alt.CAL_DATE) as rn
                           ,alt.CAL_Date as Due_Date
                       FROM myCal mn
                              INNER JOIN myCal alt ON (alt.CAL_Date > mn.CAL_Date)
                      WHERE alt.Bus_Working_Day = 1
                    ) due ON (cal.CAL_Date = due.CAL_Date AND due.rn = 10)
 ORDER BY CAL_Date
;
```

dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=69eda432335c84fda96905559bdf1239)

It requires more than a CASE statement, because you need to evaluate whether each following day is a business day or not to find the days you need.

Here's how it works:
 - join the table against itself (with `mn` as the first instance and `alt` as the second); 
 - ignore all `alt` rows where the `alt` date is less than or equal to the `mn` date (because the warning and due date will always come after the current date, of course), and where the `alt` date is not a business working day;
 - for each `mn` date, number the `alt` dates in ascending order;
 - take the calendar table, and outer join it to the results of the above twice (joining to the `mn` date) as `warn` and `due`;
 - for the join to `warn`, take the 7th `alt` date where the calendar date matches the `mn` date, for `due`, the 10th `alt` date.

You may want to consider (if possible) adding `warning_date` and `due_date` to the existing calendar table - you could modify the code above to populate the values, once the base information on the dates is in place. Saves you from joining the calendar table to itself five times to get what you want. (OK, if you have a specific date, then you can hit the `warn` and `due` subqueries directly, and don't really have to join back to the calendar table - I did that for demonstration purposes. So, only joining it to itself *4* times).

NOTE: In newer versions of Oracle, where `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` are available, you may be able to change these to a more direct (and possibly better performing) query - however, without knowing what version you've got available (and needing to use dbfiddle for my testing, where the version is 11g), I went with this solution.

You should be able to modify this to meet your needs.

UPDATE: You asked what changes would need to be made to use the query in a trigger.

Actually, now that I think about it, I'd be inclined not to use a trigger directly. You see, even if one row is added, all the rows (or, at least, all the rows whose date is, say, within 20 days before any changed date) will need to be updated - which would mean we'd have a trigger that was (technically, at least) recursive.

To avoid that, it might be better to do something somewhat more complicated (of course!).

1. Create a new table, let's call it `FLAG_JOB_TO_RUN`, and give it one column, `JOB_NAME`.
2. In your trigger, `INSERT` the value `Update_Warn_Due_Dates` into `FLAG_JOB_TO_RUN.JOB_NAME` (if it doesn't already exist).
3. Schedule a script (or, even better, create a stored procedure and schedule that) to do the following:

   - Check if there is an 'Update_Warn_Due_Dates' entry in `FLAG_JOB_TO_RUN`
   - If there is:

     - Run the `UPDATE` version of the `SELECT` query above to set `Warning_Date` and `Due_Date` for all rows in `myCal`, and
     - `DELETE` that row from `FLAG_JOB_TO_RUN`

   Run this job as often as you think is necessary.  It might suffice to run it once a night, and to manually run it right after you know there's been a major change; or, you might need to run it every 5 minutes.

Comment: First off, thank you very much for the detailed reply and the possible answer, I'm going to try this out when I get home and comment back on experience. Second, holy-crap that's much more difficult than what I thought it was. I thought I was getting pretty close with a case statement but just couldn't close the deal. I feel like I have a decent grasp of SQL and then something like this crushes my confidence like an egg. One more question, you mention altering the table to add the columns to the table, would those columns be populated via a trigger once the original date is added?

Comment: Method of population would depend on how the Business Calendar table gets updated. If it's populated one a year (or even once a month)by a short script, then I'd just fill in the warning and due dates at the end of said script. If it's *normally* populated once a year, but gets relevant "tweaks" during the year, you would probably want to use a trigger. And, I should note, I don't usually work in Oracle; while this is tested and works, I can't promise it's the best possible method - just that it's tested and works.

Comment: Is it me or is it just crazy complicated?   I'm not a really a trigger guy since its PL/SQL, just keys and current date stuff. Would that trigger look similar to the above solution?

Comment: Well, no, I thought about it and had to make it more complicated - see update. :-)

Comment: OK, will do :-)

Comment: OMG I didn't realize building in this functionality would be so complicated.

Comment: Honestly, for a human to understand, it would be easier to write it as a cursor: Pull each day up one by one, then query for the business days that come after it (with `ROW_NUMBER()`) and grabbing the 7th and 10th and then going on to the next. However, cursors are slow, and a set-based solution.is usually faster. Harder to follow, maybe, but faster. If there was a point where the calendar was graven in stone before it was used, we could just update it once then. It's always simpler when you can set the rules so it's easy - unfortunately, just not very realistic.

Comment: Just got the chance to try the first solution you provided up top and confirms that works. Although the view creation on the case statement keeps barking at me. I'll try to troubleshoot tomorrow night and report back.